# Is it possible to return the Backbone View associated with an element ID?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Given the `id` of an element, is it possible to return a Backbone View (or any Backbone object for that matter) that has been associated with that element?

A good example of what I'm looking for would be something from the world of Dojo Toolkit, where: `registry.byId('my-element-id')` will return an associated widget by its ID (see: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html).

Is there anything comparable in Backbone?

Comment: I think you mean "model", not "element"

Comment: No I mean `element`; for instance if I am associating a view to an element on the page located at `<div id="my-element-id"></div>` I want to find the view that is "attached" to that DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unless you keep track of it yourself. For example if in your BaseView you would do something like

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    this.$el.data('backbone-view', this);
  }
});
```

You could then retrieve the backbone view associated with any element like so

```
$("#my-element-id").data('backbone-view');
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought I would have to do, but figured it was worth asking to see if Backbone had a sort of registry built-in that I was just missing.